# How was the Answer Ratio in the old Magento Forum

Tags: discussion

Since the Magento Forum is read-only, people regularly mention the need for a new Forum.
While a Forum is good to discuss things, I wonder how bad the situation with questions and similar was.
My general Experience with online forums was, that if your questions moves away from the first page, the chance for an answer was nearly zero.
So I wonder how was the experience with the magento forum. How many Questions got resolved, how did cleanup of "nonsense" and "not reproducible stuff" happen and was it successful?

Comment: Well, the content is still available online, so you can write a nice perl or python script to consume & report on this :-D

Answer (score 5):

My recollection is that there was a good mix of what you describe as well as people resurrecting or tagging onto old threads (ofttimes because that was where their Google search dumped them).

The new community forum (anticipating a launch by end of April) is powered by [Lithium](http://www.lithium.com/products-solutions/online-communities/forums), and there are a number of moderating and curating tools which should help us find unanswered questions as well as merging duplicates, closing aged threads, etc.